# Как сделать правку, если редактор не считает пробелы/переносы за символы?

Tags: поддержка, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Зачастую новые (и не очень) пользователи SO задают вполне корректные вопросы, но совершенно не форматируют свой код. В таком случая правка заключается только в добавлении пробелов/переносов строки для правильного форматирования. Однако редактор SO не считает пробелы/переносы за символы и не пропускает правку без 6 изменённых символов (Да, я знаю что с большей репутацией можно исправлять всё подряд, однако как я понимаю это сделано с целью защиты от незначительных правок, а форматирование кода мне таковой не кажется).
**Собственно вопрос: как в этом случае добить 6 символов?** Обычно в таких случаях я меняю пару слов на синонимы, но эта правка кажется высосанной из пальца, да и редактировать текст вопроса без веской на то причины мне не кажется хорошей идеей. Возможно есть более правильный способ добить количество символов?

Comment: Мне кажется, что добавление после кода фразы "@nick отформатировал DDMMYY HHMM" вполне уместно

Comment: Обычно, когда вопрос задают новички, то они не используют блок кода (апостроф: ```) и, чаще всего, нарушают табуляцию. Тогда я добавляю блок кода, язык программирования и, попутно, исправляю табуляцию. За счёт блока кода набираю необходимые 6 символов.

Comment: Лично меня очень часто спасало исправление орфографии, часто бывает что падеж не тот, или буквы не на том месте, запятые в конце концов, в общем, исправление орфографии также может вам помочь. Плюс можете это записать в кратком описании, чтобы вашу правку охотнее приняли. Также, можете те части текста которые планировались как код, обернуть в обратные кавычки, допустим: `Я пробовал и querySelectorAll и getElementsByTagName` -> `Я пробовал и \`querySelectorAll\` и \`getElementsByTagName\``.

Comment: на счет правки кода, я попадался на вопросы, где решение заключалось в правильном форматировании кода, о чем говорила ошибка, указанная в вопросе. Нужно подходить осмысленно к такого рода правкам и не делать это в 100% со всеми вопросами новичков

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вариант, предложенный в комментарии - замена форматирования отступами на форматирование апострофами, имхо, достаточно хорош. Три символа в начале и три в конце как раз дадут необходимый минимум.

Но я хотел предложить и другой вариант (правда, не уверен на 100%, что он рабочий). Можно в правке добавить комментарий (не в описание правки, а в саму правку) с помощью *html* `<!-- этот текст можно удалить при принятии правки -->`.

В таком случае проверяющий может выбрать вариант "править и принять" и удалить лишний комментарий. Но даже если принятие пройдёт без удаления комментария - ничего страшного, текст комментария будет доступен только при редактировании, а при чтении сообщения отображаться не будет.

Comment: Действительно, работает

Comment: До этого даже не знал про комментарии (наверное плохо читал справку XD)

Comment: Но если нажать "править и принять", то автором правки будет считаться тот, кто утвердил правку, а не тот, кто её внёс.

Comment: @maestro по-моему там просто две ревизии будет подряд, но автор получит свои +2 репы. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1342910/revisions): ревизии 3 и 4.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в конце сообщения это:

```
<br><br><br>
```

Визуально ничего не изменится.